# How to use AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics with IFunctionsHostBuilder

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have the following Startup class for azure function:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            //some code
        }
    }
```

How could I inject here Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.AzureAppServices provider and use AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics? something like:

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
```

I use .Net Core 3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the code below in your Startup class:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp9.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp9
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            ConfigureServices(builder.Services).BuildServiceProvider(true);
        }

        private IServiceCollection ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
            });

            return services;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ivan Yang thanks for your answer. Do you know whether this should write to azure portal log stream console in app service?

Comment: I mean function -> Monitor -> Logs. Somehow output there is not complete in comparison to AppInsights logs.

Comment: @SimonD, not sure, but I think application insights should collect more since it's more powerful. And we always recommend  to use application insights for azure function:).

Comment: And it helps, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.